# Strange wikipedia mojibake (faulty coding)

Tags: asp.net, character-encoding

This is the first Wikipedia page that appears a problem to me. When I use HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream() to open this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London, it's full of mojibake. But my browser can encode it without problems.

I have used three methods to download the text file. And all of them get different files.

The first method downloaded a file of 274,851 bytes

```
    string TargetUri = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London";

    HttpWebRequest queryPage = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(TargetUri);

    queryPage.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)queryPage.GetResponse())
    {

        using (Stream PageRawCode = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (MemoryStream PageRawCodeDuplicate = new MemoryStream())
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int ByteCount;
                do
                {
                    ByteCount = PageRawCode.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    PageRawCodeDuplicate.Write(buffer, 0, ByteCount);
                } while (ByteCount > 0);

                PageRawCodeDuplicate.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                using (StreamReader CodeInUTF8 = new StreamReader(PageRawCodeDuplicate))
                {
                    string PageText = CodeInUTF8.ReadToEnd();
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"E:\My Documents\Desktop\london1.html"))
                    {
                        sw.Write(PageText);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The second method is

```
    WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
    myWebClient.DownloadFile("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London", @"E:\My Documents\Desktop\london2.html");
```

This method only downloaded a file of 152.297 bytes

The third method is to open the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London, and save the source code file. This method will get a file of 1,746,420 bytes

I don't understand why there is a such a difference using different method get a text file.

I have used ASCII, BigEndianUnicode, Unicode, UTF32, UTF7, UTF8 to read the first 2 files. None of them shows the code correctly.

then I read the hex code of the files. The first 32 characters of london1.html is

```
1FEFBFBD0800000000000003EFBFBDEF
```

The first 32 characters of london2.html is

```
1F8B0800000000000003ECFD4B8F1C49
```

Obviously they are not `<!DOCTYPE html>`

What are these two files? I don't even know how to inspect them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally mystery SOLVED! The text stream is a GZipStream. Using GZipStream decompress can read the code.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx
It's hard to imagine how much the browser does behind

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple issue in your code. You forgot to flush the memorystream. I've also added a second solution that doesn't copy the Stream in memory first...

If I run this slightly adapted code, I get a complete html file:

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)queryPage.GetResponse())
{

    using (Stream PageRawCode = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (MemoryStream PageRawCodeDuplicate = new MemoryStream())
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int ByteCount;
            do
            {
                ByteCount = PageRawCode.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                PageRawCodeDuplicate.Write(buffer, 0, ByteCount);
            } while (ByteCount > 0);

            // FLUSH!
            PageRawCodeDuplicate.Flush();

            PageRawCodeDuplicate.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            // Pick an encoding here
            using (StreamReader CodeInUTF8 = new StreamReader(
                                   PageRawCodeDuplicate, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                string PageText = CodeInUTF8.ReadToEnd();
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"london1.html"))
                {
                    sw.Write(PageText);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Direct copy of the stream**

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)queryPage.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream PageRawCode = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
            using (StreamReader CodeInUTF8 = new StreamReader(
                                                      PageRawCode, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"london1.html"))
                {
                    while (!CodeInUTF8.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(CodeInUTF8.ReadLine());
                    }
                 }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But I can't testify your solution right now, because the page occasionally has problem, but not always. It works at this moment.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you flush it or not. It doesn't work. If you are interested, please try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/wikipedia It's not working today. I don't know why you want to flush the stream.

Comment: The reason I use memorystream is because some Japanese/Chinese website use Shift-JIS/Big5 etc, in which ascii code is recognised but the Asian characters cannot be properly interpreted.

Comment: The memorystream is not going to fix that. I beleive you can use `Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet)` to try to get an encoding that matches the response stream.

Comment: have you tried en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia ?? What CharacterSet is that?

Comment: You don't know, because you have never implemented. Did you know you can only read your data stream once? For that reason memorystream is used